# Explode and Implode in APL

Tags: php, arrays, string, apl

How could functions similar to PHP's `explode` and `implode` be implemented with APL?

I tried to work it out myself and came up with a solution which I'm posting below. I'd like to see other ways that this might be solved.

Comment: If you want to put your code under review, Programmers might be more fitting as they allow code-reviews: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ - Albeit Self Answering Questions is valid here as well, so I don't vote to mark as off-topic. -- For Reference (Wikipedia):  [APL (programming language)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APL_(programming_language))

Comment: @hakre - I wasn't really looking for review, but I welcome it anyway.

Comment: Code reviews would go on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ rather than programmers, though this is fine here I think.  Especially as the APL community is very small, not going to get seen on the other sites, much less answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pé, the quest for "short" and/or "elegant" solutions to standard-problems in APL is older than PHP and even older than new terminology, such as "explode", "implode" (I think - but I must admit I do not know how old these terms really are...). Anyway, the early APL guys used the term "idiom" for such "solutions to standard problems that fit in one line of APL".
And for some reason, the Finns were especially creative and even started producing a list of these in order to make it easy for newbies. And I find this stuff still useful after 20yrs of doing APL. It is called "FinnAPL" - the Finnish APL idiom library and you can browse it here: https://aplwiki.com/wiki/FinnAPL_idiom_library (*BTW, the whole APL Wiki might be interesting to read...*)

You may, however, need to be creative with your wording in order to find solutions ;)
And one warning: FinnAPL only works with "classic" (non-nested) data-structures (*nested matrices came with "APL2" which is standard these days*), so some of the ways they handle data might no longer be "state-of-the-art". (i.e. back in the "old times", CAT BIRD and DOG would have been represented as a 3x4 array, so "implode" of string-array was a simple as `,array,delimeter` (but you then had the challenge to remove blanks which were inserted for padding.

Anyway, I'm not sure why I wrote all this - just a few thoughts which came to mind when thinking about my start with APL ;-)

Ok, let me also look at the question. When your delimeter is a single character the APL2ish-idiomatic way of handling this would be something like this:

```
⎕ml←3    ⍝ "migration-level" (only Dyalog APL) to ensure APL2-compatibility
s←' '
A←s,'BIRD',s,'CAT',s,'DOG'     ⍝ note that delimeter also used as 1st char!
exploded_string←1↓¨(+\A=s)⊂A   ⍝ explode
imploded←∊s,¨exploded_string
A≡imploded                     ⍝ test for successfull round-trip should return 1
```

Comment: I did this as an exercise to familiarize myself with APL, and it's been a great learning experience, especially now that I see the idiomatic solution. And thanks for the link to the Finn library!

Comment: I sympathize - you're out for a great adventure there! :-)

Probably every APLer has his toolbox which addresses such tasks, and the refinements of these tools can be a life-long journey ;-)

Comment: It's a nice explode, though only deals with single character separators, as the `A=s` bit faults with a length error.  The technique might be adapted though.  One useful aspect of this method is it preserves the empty partition where two separators are adjoining.  Change A to `A←s,'BIRD',s,s,'CAT',s,'DOG'` then try `0=⍴¨exploded_string` to see the empty set.

Answer (score 2):

**Explode:**

Given the following text string and delimiter string:

```
F←'CAT BIRD DOG'
B←' '
```

Explode can be accomplished as follows:

```
S←⍴,B
P←(⊃~∨/(-S-⍳S)⌽¨S⍴⊂B⍷F)⊂F
P[2] ⍝ returns BIRD
```

**Limitations:**

PHP's explode function returns a null array value when two delimiters are adjacent to each other. The code above simply ignores that and treats the two delimiters as if they were one.

The code above also does nothing to handle overlapping delimiters. This is most likely to occur if repeated characters are used for the delimiter. For example:

```
F←'CATaaaBIRDaaDOG'
B←'aa'
S←⍴,B
P←(⊃~∨/(-S-⍳S)⌽¨S⍴⊂B⍷F)⊂F
P ⍝ returns CAT BIRD DOG
```

However, the expected result would be `CAT aBIRD DOG` because it doesn't recognize 'aaa' as the delimiter followed by 'a.' Rather, it treats it as two overlapping delimiters, which end up functioning as a single delimiter. Another example would be 'tat' as the delimiter, in which case, any occurence in the string of 'tatat' would have the same problem.

**Overlapping Delimiters:**

I have an alternative for the possibility of a single overlap:

```
S←⍴,B
A←B⍷F
A←(2×A)>⊃+/(-S-⍳S)⌽¨S⍴⊂A
P←(⊃~∨/(-S-⍳S)⌽¨S⍴⊂A)⊂F
```

The third line of code eliminates any string positions that occur within a distance of `S-1` characters from any delimiter position before it. As I said, this only solves the problem for a single overlap. If there are two or more overlaps, the first is recognized as a delimiter, and all the rest are ignored. Here's an example of two overlaps:

```
F←'CATtatatatBIRDtatDOG'
B←'tat'
S←⍴,B
A←B⍷F
A←(2×A)>⊃+/(-S-⍳S)⌽¨S⍴⊂A
P←(⊃~∨/(-S-⍳S)⌽¨S⍴⊂A)⊂F
P ⍝ returns CAT atatBIRD DOG
```

The expected result was 'CAT a BIRD DOG,' but it is unable to recognize the final 'tat' as a delimiter because of the overlap. Such a situation would be rare except when repeated characters are used. If the delimiter is 'aa', then 'aaaa' would be considered a double overlap, and only the first delimiter would be recognized.

**Implode:**

Much simpler:

```
P←'CAT' 'BIRD' 'DOG'
B←'-'
(⍴,B)↓∊B,¨P
```

It returns 'CAT-BIRD-DOG' as expected.

Comment: It's a nice solution for the explode, I like the use of `(-S-⍳S)` with the rotate `⌽` to match the whole separator.  Standard technique I assume, but still nice to see.  To get round the overlaps, you might need to tokenize the separators with an unused character, then use a different token between two adjacent separator tokens added in to represent an empty set.

Comment: @Orbling - Thanks for the comment. I'm new to APL, so I don't know if it's standard technique or not. It's just what made sense at the time.

Answer (score 1):

An interesting alternative for implode can be accomplished with reduction:

```
      p←'cat' 'bird' 'dog'
      ↑{⍺,'-',⍵}/p
cat-bird-dog
```

This technique does not need to explicitly reference the shape of the delimiter.

And an interesting alternative to explode can be done with n-wise reduction:

```
      f←'CATtatBIRDtatDOG'
      b←'tat'
      b{(~(-⍴⍵)↑(⍴⍺)∨/⍺⍷⍵)⊂⍵}f
 CAT  BIRD  DOG
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's getting late here, so I'll have to give it a closer look tomorrow. However, one thing that throws me is that I'm using NARS2000 which doesn't support the curly brackets, and I'm not familiar with the curly-bracket syntax. I'll work on deciphering it tomorrow.

Comment: The curly brackets are used for "dynamic functions" which are a vendor-specific extension and were invented by Dyalog. (There is also a free version available for personal use from Dyalog, if you're interested - and you can also try APL online @ http://tryapl.org )

Comment: I assigned your explode code to `P`, and the result of `P[3]` was "Ttat" instead of the expected "DOG."

Comment: @PédeLeão: Nice to see someone else using NARS2000, it's what I've always used.  Dyalog is great, but does have a lot of proprietary extensions - always causes hassle in questions and answers, as most people assume you're using Dyalog.

Comment: As the dyadic dynamic function on the explode is effectively just doing `⍵←f ⋄ ⍺←b`, it'll run in anything else by just swapping out the letters: `(~(-⍴f)↑(⍴b)∨/b⍷f)⊂f`.

Comment: I do like this method, the only slight issue is that if the separator occurs within the first `⍴b` characters, then it messes up the removal of the initial separator due to the take pulling in zeros to make up the length in the front.  If the initial digit is 1 before the take, then making sure the set starts with `⍴b` ones prefixing as necessary, before the take, would fix that I think.